# How to pipe (in bash) standard output to a variable, and stderr to a command

Tags: bash, stdout, pipe, stderr

I have a pipe like this:

```
VAR=`command1 | command2 | etc...`
```

And I would like that, if the pipe finishes succesfully, the output is saved in `VAR`, and otherwise, if the pipe fails in any point of the pipe, error is sended to a command. That command write then errors with a certain format to a some file. Something like that (but this doesn't work):

```
VAR=`{ command1 | command2 | etc... ; } 2> err_command`
```

I've tried other combinations:

```
|& err_command
2>&1 | err_command
```

But they don't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use process substitution.

```
VAR=`{ command1 | command2 | etc... ; } 2> >(err_command)`
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. I would swear that I've tried this before :S hehe. Thank you.